# Using Lagrange multipliers to find minimum value

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum value of

$$ T = \frac {a}{v \cos \alpha}  + \frac {b}{v\cos\beta} $$

subject to the constraint

$$ L = a\tan \alpha + b\tan\beta $$

where $a, b, v$ and $L$ are all constants.

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

While **Tom** is basically correct that this optimization problem "smells like Snell's", it is missing something significant, which presumably got omitted somewhere in stating the function to be minimized.

The intent of the problem from the poser was likely to show how the description of light refraction referred to as "Snell's Law" comes from a determination of the path for a "ray" of light requiring the least amount of time to pass from a point in one optical medium to another with a different refractive index.  A diagram of the physical situation might look like this:

[image]

There are two media with a simple interface between them (represented here by a horizontal line).  The light ray is traced from a point at a distance $ \ a \ $ "above" the interface to a second point a distance $ \ b \ $ "below" that line.

The differing optical properties of the two media changes the speed and direction of the light ray.  The convention is to measure the angle that the ray makes to a "vertical" (normal) line to the interface.  If we call $ \ c \ $ the speed of light "in vacuum", and the "refractive indices" of the two media $ \ n_1 \ $ and $ \ n_2 \ $ , then the (constant) speeds of the light ray passing through the two media are $ \ v_1 \ = \ \frac{c}{n_1} \ $ and $ \ v_2 \ = \ \frac{c}{n_2} \ $ , respectively.

The "vertical component" of the velocity of the ray in the medium above the interface is then $ \ v_1 \ \cos \alpha \ $ and in the medium below, $ \ v_2 \ \cos \beta \ $ .  The total time required for the ray to travel from the "initial" to "final" point is then

$$ T \ = \ \frac{a}{v_1 \ \cos \alpha} \ + \ \frac{b}{v_2 \ \cos \beta} \ \ . $$

The constraint that is usually imposed in minimizing this "total time function" of the two angle variables $ \ \alpha \ $ and $ \ \beta \ $ is to use the *fixed* "horizontal" separation between the two endpoints,

$$ L \ = \ a \ \tan \alpha \ + \ b \ \tan \beta \ \ .  $$

[Note from the physical arrangement that the angles have "first quadrant" values.]

The Lagrange-multiplier calculation then proceeds as **Tom** suggests, producing the equations

$$ \frac{a}{v_1} \ \sec \alpha \ \tan \alpha \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ a \ \sec^2 \alpha \ \ , \ \ \frac{b}{v_2} \ \sec \beta \ \tan \beta \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ b \ \sec^2 \beta    $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{v_1}  \cdot  \frac{\tan \alpha}{\sec \alpha} \ = \ \frac{1}{v_2}  \cdot  \frac{\tan \beta}{\sec \beta} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{\sin \alpha}{v_1} \  = \ \frac{\sin \beta}{v_2} \ \ . $$

If we replace the speeds with the expressions above relating them to the refractive indices, we obtain the familiar expression of "Snell's Law",

$$   \frac{\sin \alpha}{c \ / \ n_1} \  = \ \frac{\sin \beta}{c \ / \ n_2} \ \  \Rightarrow \ \  n_1 \ \sin \alpha \  = \ n_2 \ \sin \beta \ \ . $$

The statement of the problem posted by **Drey1** , without the subscripts, would have a single speed for the light ray between the two points, which would then just lead to $ \ \alpha \ = \ \beta \ $ (since the angles are in the first quadrant).  The path is then a straight line through an effectively  uniform medium, as we would expect.

To answer the question concerning the minimum *time* for the transit of the light ray, we have an "underdetermined" problem, in the sense that we can only find one of the angles in terms of the other.  Since the distances $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ and the speeds $ \ v_1 \ $ and $ \ v_2 \ $ are set by the physical situation, we can choose the "entry angle" $ \ \alpha \ $ as the "independent variable" to write

$$ \left( \frac{v_2}{v_1} \right)^2 \ \sin^2 \alpha \  = \ \sin^2 \beta \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \frac{v_2}{v_1} \right)^2 \ \sin^2 \alpha \  = \ 1 \ - \ \cos^2 \beta $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \cos \beta \ = \ \sqrt{ \ 1 \ - \ \left( \frac{v_2}{v_1} \right)^2 \ \sin^2 \alpha} \ \ . $$

Inserting this result into the "total time" for the travel of the light ray yields

$$ T_{min} (\alpha) \ = \ \frac{a}{v_1 \ \cos \alpha} \ + \ \frac{b}{v_2 \ \sqrt{ \ 1 \ - \ \left( \frac{v_2}{v_1} \right)^2 \ \sin^2 \alpha}} \ \ . $$

[There is a limitation to the applicability of this result in passing from one medium to a second where $ \ v_1 \ < \ v_2 \ $ : there will then be a "critical angle" at which the behavior of the ray changes from refraction to "total internal reflection".]

With the two speeds for the ray equal (the "uniform medium" condition), this result simplifies to $ \ T \ = \ \frac{a \ + \ b}{ \cos \alpha}  \ $ , which is correct for the "straight-line" path.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like Snell's.

*Hint:* Let $g(\alpha, \beta) = a \tan\alpha + b \tan \beta - L$. You need to set up the following system of equations:

$$L = a \tan \alpha + b \tan \beta$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial \alpha} = \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial \alpha}$$
$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial \beta} = \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial \beta}$$

This is a system of $3$ equations with $3$ unknowns and your job is to try and find for what values of $\alpha, \beta$, and $\lambda$ this system is satisfied. However, when using Lagrange multipliers, you might want to think of $\lambda$ as a tool to get to the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make this system of equations consistent, since at the end of the day, you don't want the values of $\lambda$, but rather just the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. When you find the points $(\alpha, \beta)$ (there could be more than $1$ point), you can evaluate your function $T$ to see what values they give.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Refer to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Then let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be the variables.